# What are the list of all the algorithms for Natural Language processing (NLP)?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I know it is a little bit wide topic but all I am looking for is if someone can help me with the list of all the NLP algorithms and when to use them, or maybe a resource which I can refer. for example - **RNN **might be a good use case for a question and answer NLP use case and a simple dense network might just work quite good for binary segregation of documents or identify sarcastic comments from useful news.

I was hoping we can add to the list below from whatever anyone has an idea about will be great. Of course, the below list is not a hard and fast rule and more often than not on various use case we might have to try different things approaches but this is an effort just to have an exhaustive list for NLP algorithms.

Dense layer - useful for document segregation or (sarcastic comments from useful news)
RNN(LSTM) - Good for Question and Answer API

Answer (score 1):

You can find some research publication [here](https://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/) for different set of application in the domain of natural language processing.

And also you can find some resources in google scholar.